# Problems importing timestamp from Parquet files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm exporting data into Parquet files and importing it into Snowflake. The export is done with python (using `to_parquet` from `pandas`) on a Windows Server machine.

The exported file has several timestamp columns. Here's the metadata of one of these columns (ParquetViewer):

[image: Metadata]

I'm having weird issues trying to import the timestamp columns into Snowflake.

**Attempt 1 (using the `copy into`):**

```
create or replace table STAGING.DIM_EMPLOYEE(
    "EmployeeID" NUMBER(38,0),
    "ExitDate" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
);

copy into STAGING.DIM_EMPLOYEE
from @S3
pattern='dim_Employee_.*.parquet'
file_format = (type = parquet)
match_by_column_name = case_insensitive;

select * from STAGING.DIM_EMPLOYEE;
```

The timestamp column is not imported correctly:

[image: Invalid date]

It seems that Snowflake assumes that the value in the column is in seconds and not in microseconds and therefore converts incorrectly.

**Attempt 2 (using the external tables):**

Then I created an external table:

```
create or replace external table STAGING.EXT_DIM_EMPLOYEE(
    "EmployeeID" NUMBER(38,0) AS (CAST(GET($1, 'EmployeeID') AS NUMBER(38,0))),
    "ExitDate" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) AS (CAST(GET($1, 'ExitDate') AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)))
)
location=@S3
pattern='dim_Employee_.*.parquet'
file_format='parquet'
;

SELECT * FROM STAGING.EXT_DIM_EMPLOYEE;
```

The data is still incorrect - still the same issue (seconds instead of microseconds):

[image: Invalid date, try 2]

**Attempt 3 (using the external tables, with modified TO_TIMESTAMP):**

I've then modified the external table definition to specifically define that microseconds are used `TO_TIMESTAMP_TNZ` with scale parameter 6:

```
create or replace external table STAGING.EXT_DIM_EMPLOYEE_V2(
    "EmployeeID" NUMBER(38,0) AS (CAST(GET($1, 'EmployeeID') AS NUMBER(38,0))),
    "ExitDate" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) AS (TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(TO_NUMBER(GET($1, 'ExitDate')), 6))
)
location=@CHICOREE_D365_BI_STAGE/
pattern='dim_Employee_.*.parquet'
file_format='parquet'
;

SELECT * FROM STAGING.EXT_DIM_EMPLOYEE_V2;
```

Now the data is correct:

[image: correct exitdate, try 3]

But now the "weird" issue appears:

- I can load the data into a table, but the load is quite slow and I get a `Querying (repair)` message during the load. However, at the end, the query is executed, albeit slow:

[image: querying-repair]

- I want to load the data from stored procedure, using SQL script. When executing the statement using the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` an error is returned:

[image: sql internal error]

```
DECLARE
    SQL STRING;
BEGIN
    SET SQL := 'INSERT INTO STAGING.DIM_EMPLOYEE ("EmployeeID", "ExitDate") SELECT "EmployeeID", "ExitDate" FROM STAGING.EXT_DIM_EMPLOYEE_V2;';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL;
END;
```

I have also tried to define the timestamp column in an external table as a `NUMBER`, import it and later convert it into timestamp. This generates the same issue (returning `SQL execution internal error` in SQL script).

Has anyone experienced an issue like this - it seems to me like a bug?

Basically - my goal is to generate insert/select statements dynamically and execute them (in stored procedures). I have a lot of files (with different schemas) that need to be imported and I want to create an "universal logic" to load these Parquet files into Snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is outdated, please use the below COPY INTO command:

`COPY INTO DIM_EMPLOYEE FROM (SELECT $1:EmployeeID::NUMBER, TO_TIMESTAMP($1:ExitDate::NUMBER, 6) FROM @my_stage) FILE_FORMAT = (type = parquet);`

Comment: Also, feel free to use this workaround for the COPY INTO command:
`COPY INTO DIM_EMPLOYEE FROM
(SELECT $1:EmployeeID::NUMBER, TO_TIMESTAMP($1:ExitDate::NUMBER, 6) FROM @my_stage)
FILE_FORMAT = (type = parquet);`